# Misplaced IRS EIP 3rd payment

Tags: united-states, irs, stimulus

I received the IRS EIP **3rd** payment via paper check, but lost it. How does one have check re-issued?
Not seeing scenario here on the [IRS FAQ site](https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/get-my-payment-frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: Is the IRS telling you they sent the payment and it never arrived?  Was this an electronic deposit or paper check?  We need more info to help you.

Comment: @SRiverNet Paper check arrived but was misplace/lost. Comments updated

Answer (score 1):

I found a link on the IRS web site that answers your question (webpage states it is for the first payment, but it should still apply) - [IRS Newsroom](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/questions-and-answers-about-the-first-economic-impact-payment-topic-f-payment-issued-but-lost-stolen-destroyed-or-not-received)

Specifically:

> you may need to request a payment trace so the IRS can determine if your payment was cashed

If the check was never cashed, they will "credit your account" but will not issue another check.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Yep, just looks like I may have to wait a set time before initiating trace.